# solr grouping based on all index values

Tags: solr, grouping

When I group or facet in solr based on a field, I only receive a count of documents that are in the search results. Is there a way to get a count of the documents that contain that value across the entire index? 
For example, with this data, I would like to search for "something" and get back only one item per unique gs field with a count of all the fields in the index. So id 2 would come up, as grouped by gs 50005, but the count would be 2 instead of 1.

```
<doc>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="gs">50005</field>
<field name="text">blah</field>
</doc>

<doc>
<field name="id">2</field>
<field name="gs">50005</field>
<field name="text">something else</field>
</doc>

<doc>
<field name="id">3</field>
<field name="gs">123</field>
<field name="text">another something value</field>
</doc>

<doc>
<field name="id">4</field>
<field name="gs">5423</field>
<field name="text">something entirely different</field>
</doc>
```

Comment: use `facet.query`.. as `facet.query=gs:50005`, you will get the appearance of `50005` in entire index

Comment: Hi, how can I get that count for each document in the results?

Comment: have u tried the query with above parameters?

Comment: Hi Suhel, I may not have elaborated correctly. I essentially need docfreq value for each returned document. I am trying to include a function in my query: fl=t:docfreq(gs,field(gs)) which doesn't work, however fl=t:docfreq(gs,5423) returns the correct result, but for a specific gs code. Naturally, the value for each document would be different depending on the frequency of that code in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a work around: 
{!join from=gs to=gs}gs:field(gs) text:something&group=true&group.field=gs

Essentially, the way this works is the query is expanded through a join to include all items that have that same gs and then it is grouped by gs. Through grouping I have a value in XML of how many items are in the group.

Not very elegant, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge no. Why don't you add them up based on the facet counts in your client code?

Comment: That is an option that we would like to avoid. Even with facet counts, I would only get the counts for the result set and not across the entire index.

Comment: The only way you can get across the index is by issues separate query with *:* to get net facets, by setting rows 1. Because a "query response" obviously includes processing of q parameter. Solr works through handler and handler components are executed in an order using what query component qualified as the docset.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks. I have also been playing around with a function to return the count, but can't get it to run fl=docfreq(gs,field(gs)) hard coded value works, and field(gs) works separately as well, but they don't work together :(