# Merging Solr query results through SolrNet

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm using Sorl v3.6.1 and have successfully managed to index data as well as using Apache Tika to index binary items. I'm using `SolrNet` to pull this data out. However I have an issue whereby I want to link 2 results together.

Now consider the following XML (this is just for illustration purposes):

```
<doc>
    <id>263</id>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <summary>This is the summary<summary/>
    <binary_id>994832</binary_id>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>994832</id>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <summary>This is the summary<summary/>
    <text>this is the contents of the binary</text>
</doc>
```

Is it possible (through SolrNet) to merge the two above results together so when a user searches for  **This is the contents of the binary** it also returns the data in the first item?

In my example you can see the first item contains the id of the binary (994832) so my initial thoughts are that I need to do 2 queries and somehow merge them?

Not really sure about how to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something funky with a join kind of query, however beware of performance impacts. Here is my post from some time ago where I was trying to do something similar. 
[solr grouping based on all index values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549260/solr-grouping-based-on-all-index-values)

Alternatively, a better solution, IF and only IF you can massage the data a bit before going in. Would be to assign the same ID to all documents that need to be retrieved as a group,  per your example, this would be to add binaryid field to the second doc and assign 994832 value to it. You would be able to very cleanly use Solr grouping to group the items as one and then group sorting to only return the item that you want.